# "Hello, world!" - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

Computer OS: Windows 7
Language: Java

After long time back I am using java, I am getting problem while running the hello world program:

```
public class Hello 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
         System.out.println ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I saved this code in Hello.java File, and then compiled using cmd:

```
C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>javac -version
javac 1.6.0

C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>javac Hello.java

C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>java Hello
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello

C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>
```

Can you explain why the error message above was thrown?

Comment: Run `dir` command. Do you see `Hello.class` there? If yes, is there any package declaration in your `Hello.java` file?

Comment: Do you see a file called "Hello.class" on your Desktop?

Comment: You are missing a right `}`. Or is that just C & P error to StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes Hello.java class is created after javac

Comment: Hello.java is something different from Hello.class

Comment: @ merlin2011, I am not missing, I forgot to write in post, sorry

Comment: As an aside: you should move on from Java 6 - it's no longer officially supported.

Comment: I checked with java jdk1.7.0, getting same error, Hello.class is created @MOk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing one "}" at the end of the program

```
public class Hello 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
       System.out.println ("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and then try

```
java -cp . Hello
```

Comment: I missed this curly braces while posting, This code is compiling, but not running.

Comment: java -cp . Hello, It worked, can you tell me reason why its not working using 'java Hello' command, previously as I remember I used to run it using java 'ClassName'

Comment: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/ @yogeshkmrsoni

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni Ok, if it worked with this, then you should change your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to include `.` in it.

Comment: •If CLASSPATH environment variable is not found, current folder (".") is used by default

Comment: @Neel Only if it is not set. But if it is set to some path, and `.` is not included, it will not consider the current directory.

Comment: My systemvariable CLASSPATH variable value is .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;.; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin; .; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib;.;             ------- And My PATH variable value is .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin    ------------ so what I am missing?

Answer (score 6):

try this one:

```
java -cp . Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
java -cp . Hello
```

I think you do not have the current directory on your classpath

Comment: @RClaven - downvoting this answer ( which is almost certainly correct ) because it doesn't make your code work is a trifle unfair.

Comment: My class file was in bin folder of the project so, `java -cp ./bin Hello` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

try to remove

```
package package.path;
```

wish this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced exactly the same error and I've got around it changing the directory where I had both my HelloWorld.java file and the HelloWorld.class file created with javac.

I had first tried all different ways to force the classpath with no success.

The only difference I appreciate between the two directories is that the first one's path had directories containing spaces in their directory names. I need to investigate further.

Not sure why my javac works in both directories but java doesn't.

EDIT: I've now tried again in the first directory and it has worked just fine. No idea why it wasn't working before and now unable to repeat the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you did. The way I resolved it was by removing the package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

remove the package declaration and rerun

javac myprogram.java

Answer (score 0):

this might help someone down the line who has latest version  like java 1.8.0_201

set the classpath properly in environment variables.

**JAVA_HOME** = **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201**
**CLASSPATH**  =   **%JAVA_HOME%\lib.;**

append this **JAVA_HOME** in **PATH** environment variable

**note:**
remeber to put **"."** after **lib** folder to load all the Classes in **CLASSPATH** var.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you did.
I use eclipse to write the JAVA code. I resolve the problem by choosing the default choice of Project layout "Create separate folders for sources and class files" when I create a new JAVA project.
The problem will occur when I choose the "Use project folder as root for sources and class files"
[image of Project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VrUb.png)

Answer (score 0):

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.              .........................................................................................................ERROR OUTPUT

Path is an environment variable used to access the java binaries like java or javac that are used to run java programs and compile java source files. Path can be overridden by Java Settings. Path is used by operating system to find any binary or command typed in shell.

Command used to set Path:-   In window 10  Environment Variables enter the following

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\JDK1.8.0_121\bin

Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld    ...........................................................................................ERROR OUTPUT

Try this to correct the error

java -cp . HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

Set the classpath and class properly in command prompt.

Follow the below steps:

1. In command prompt copy your jdk->bin path as below:
   `C:\Users\SP\Desktop\Java>set class="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib";`
2. Then Copy jre->lib path and past it in cmd prompt with `\rt.jar` as below:
   `C:\Users\SP\Desktop\Java>set classpath="C:\Program  Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\rt.jar";`

After doing above changes try to run your program With `javac HelloWorld.java`
& `java HelloWorld` command.