# OS X, can't run create .class files. Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, macos

The following file is named `HelloWorldApp.java` and is saved on the desktop

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Joe!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

I compiled it from the terminal using `javac /Users/joe/Desktop/HelloWorldApp.java`
I then try to run it using `java /Users/joe/Desktop/HelloWorldApp` and I got the error `Error: Could not find or load main class`. I tried rerunning the command with `.class` as the end. No luck. I tried adding `sers/joe/Desktop/HelloWorldApp.class` to the PATH variable, no luck.

What is wrong? I'm using OS X 10.9.4 and can run Java programs fine inside Netbeans.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285290/hello-world-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java` command expects the fully qualified name of the class. The corresponding `.class` file must be in the classpath.

If your class is not in any package,

```
java HelloWorldApp
```

will do the trick, assuming that `HelloWorldApp.class` is in the current working directory.

If your class is in some package,

```
java -cp /the-classpath-root com.example.HelloWorldApp
```

will do the trick, assuming `HelloWorldApp.class` is in `/the-classpath-root/com/example`.

Comment: Where does the information `/the-classpath-root com.example.` come from?

Comment: @cele That would be the directory where your `.class` files exist, nested in the directories representing their package hierarchy. It could also be a `.jar` file.

Comment: does it always start with `com`? For example if the source code had `package abc;` what would it be?

Comment: @Celeritas That was just an example. In that case, it would be `abc`.

Comment: hmm I'm still getting the error. What I really want to run is the file `Users/joe/NetBeansProjects/Quicksort v4/build/classes/quicksort/TestRent.class` in the package `guide`. I've tried lots of things but doesn't work.

Comment: @Celeritas The java class `TestRent` is declared to be in the package `guide`? If so, then it shouldn't be in the location you've just told us. It should be in `../classes/guide/TestRent.class` and you should be running `java -cp <wtv>/classes guide.TestRent`.

Comment: so that package a class is in makes a difference to where it's run from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke java with a specific command-line, from the correct directory:

```
cd /Users/joe/Desktop/
java HelloWorldApp
```

I would strongly recommend using an IDE such as Eclipse, as it hides the intricacies of building and running on the command-line (especially with classpaths/libraries), and lets you focus on the code itself.